# IPv6 only LAN with NAT64 router for Internet

Tags: dns, nat, ipv6, ipv4

I want to disable IPv4 on my LAN and run only IPv6. I will use a NAT64 Juniper firewall to provide Internet access since I only have IPv4 Internet.

Will this break applications? Will I be able to play games like Dota 2 which connect to external IPv4 servers? I know properly coded applications will not break, but I suspect most of them will break when the PC has no IPv4 address.

Comment: Try it and see?

Comment: I understand that all IPv4 destined connections will fail. Only connections that are prefixed to IPv6 via DNS64 will succeed. Unless the application specifically prefixes remote IPv4 addresses with IPv6 the connections will fail. Is there some Windows service which can do this automatically for IPv4-only apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not feasible. A large amount of applications break. Only IPv6 aware applications are actually able to connect to IPv4 servers by IP address. IPv6 unaware applications can only connect to IPv4 servers if they use hostnames that are spoofed by DNS64.